# Widget for weather app how to get LocationTracker

Tags: location, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, glance-appwidget, glance

I would like to make simple widget for my weather app, to show local temperature. My question is: how to get the **LocationTracker** in my widget class?

```
class Widget: GlanceAppWidget() {...}
```

Comment: So, I find solution:

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I use fusedLocationProviderClient

```
//client
                
val locationProviderClient =
                        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
```

So, my method get location:

```
>   //get location
    private suspend fun getCurrentLocation(
        context: Context,
        locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    ): Location? {
        val hasAccessFineLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        val hasAccessCoarseLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        val isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        if (!hasAccessCoarseLocationPermission || !hasAccessFineLocationPermission || !isGpsEnabled) {
            return null
        }

        return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
            locationClient.lastLocation.apply {
                if (isComplete) {
                    if (isSuccessful) {
                        cont.resume(result)
                    } else {
                        cont.resume(null)
                    }
                    return@suspendCancellableCoroutine
                }
                addOnSuccessListener {
                    cont.resume(it)
                }
                addOnFailureListener {
                    cont.resume(null)
                }
                addOnCanceledListener {
                    cont.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```